# How to create a new column based on data out from a query

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have a quick question.

ATtaching the SS for reference.

How can i set a new column 'Status' as NO  based the nvl condition if the id is null then i have to map to the corresponding of another table .

[image]

Comment: Tag which flavor of RDBMS you are using.

Comment: i am using snowflake

Comment: Its more clear if you include sample data in text form along with the expected output. Also do not tag multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using case statement.

```
select
    nvl(b.id,a.id) as id
    ,b.name
    ,case when nvl(b.id,a.id) is null then 'No' else 'Yes' End as Status
from dd b,
(select id, name from demo group by id, name)a
where a.id=b.id(+)
```